# Stuck on a combinations algo question

Tags: algorithms

There are **x** digits and **y** boxes where **y** is between 1 and x inclusive. I have to print all the possible digits in boxes (combinations) in any order.

For examples, if **x = 5** and **y = 2** we can have the following 4 combinations:

```
1234 5
123 45
12 345
1 2345
```

Similarly if **x = 5** and **y = 3**

```
123 4 5
12 34 5
12 3 45
1 234 5
1 23 45
1 2 345
```

if **x = 5** and **y = 5** then there is only 1 combination

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Both x and y are variable and I can't figure out even a brute force way of doing this. I have tried using three nested `for` loops but have no luck.

Comment: **Hint:** You want to populate $y-1$ spaces between $x$ numbers. Can you use a recursive algorithm

Comment: You can partition X into Y different parts and then make all different permutation of all the different way to partition for example 5 can be partitioned into 3 parts in 2 ways as 1 2 2 and 1 1 3. Now you can permute this 2 arrays and get all the combinations required.

Comment: This is a nice programming exercise, which I encourage you to work out on your own, along the lines of orezvani's hint.

Comment: Do the numbers look familiar? This is a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can print numbers 1 to $x$ and print $y-1$ spaces between them in a brute force manner. The following algorithm does that:

```
function enumerate(string str, int s, int t, int y):
   /* base case: there is no space left and we print the string */
   if (y==0)
      string str2 = "";
      for i=s to t:
         str2.append(i);
       print str+str2;
       return ;

   /* recursive case: add one space and recursively call the function */
   for i=s to t:
      string str2 = "";
      for j=s to i-1:
         str2.append(j);
      str2.append("~");
      if (t-i >= y-1) call enumerate(str+str2, i, t, y-1);
```

You can call `enumerate(str="", s=1, t=5, y=2)` to print all combinations of numbers 1 to 5 and 2 spaces between them, which gives you a sorted embedding of numbers 1 to 5 in **3** boxes.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on orezvani's hint:

If you have `x` balls and `y` boxes, how many balls can you put in the first box?

- If there is only one box, you have to put all the balls in it.
- Otherwise, you must leave at least `y - 1` to be able to put one in
  each of the other boxes.

However many you choose, you will be left with a similar problem. Cue recursive function ...